# Rails generates path with wrong id when I use SimpleDelegator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have

```
= link_to order_item_path(item)
```

and `item` is instance of actual `OrderItem`, decorated with

```
module CartPage
  class ItemDecorator < SimpleDelegator
    include ViewHelpers
    include BookCoverHelpers

    def initialize(order_item)
      @order_item = order_item
      super(order_item.book)
    end

    attr_reader :order_item
    delegate :id, to: :order_item

  end
end
```

the thing is `order_item_path(item)` actually get id from book and omit `delegate :id, to: :order_item`

I know I can do `order_item_path(id: item.id)`, but I don't want to, I want to know which method actually uses rails to get id and I want to override that method

P.S.
because I also have

```
  - items.each do |item|
    = fields_for 'items[]', item do |item_fields|
      ..
```

where `fields_for` gets wrong id (id from book) too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all right, I have found answer

```
delegate :id, :to_param, to: :order_item
```